# In octave, printf gives strange error

Tags: linux, matrix, printf, cell, octave

In GNU Octave, I'm getting an error with this code.

```
A = cell(10,1);
A{5,1} = "foobar";
outputFile = fopen("mytext.txt", "w");
printf(outputFile, "%s", A{5,1});
```

I get this error:

```
error: printf: format TEMPLATE must be a string
```

This error message is not Helpful, The google does not know what this error is!  what is wrong?

Comment: The format template is the first argument to `printf` (`outputFile` in your example), and needs to be a string.  `outputFile` is a file handle, not a string, so you get the error you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the solution to this error.**

The very first parameter you are passing into `printf` MUST be a valid format string.  You are passing it a file handle.  If you want to pass a file handle, you should be using `fprintf` instead.  If you specify a first parameter as a file, printf gives you the above error.

You should be doing this instead:

```
A = cell(10,1);
A{5,1} = "foobar";
outputFile = fopen("mytext.txt", "w");
fprintf(outputFile, "%s", A{5,1});
```

Or, if you wanted to print to the screen, remove the outputFile parameter:

```
A = cell(10,1);
A{5,1} = "foobar";
outputFile = fopen("mytext.txt", "w");
printf("%s", A{5,1});
% Here printf successfully casts the cell as a string.  no error.
```

You are passing bad parameters to printf and Octave tries to make sense of nonsense.  Review this webpage to see what can and cannot be passed into octave's printf:

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Formatted-Output.html#doc-printf

Comment: Not really clear how the error message could be better -- it's succinct and to the point.  The format parameter needs to be a string and you're giving it something that isn't a string.

Comment: As you can see above, the answer part clearly shows printf successfully accepting A{5,1} as a string.  If you pass a filehandle to printf (which you shouldn't), it tells you the format is wrong, but the format is fine.  The error should read: "printf: outputFile not valid parameter".